# libmcrypt and MS Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cryptography, mcrypt

Has anyone tried using libmcrypt and visual c++? I was trying to use Crypto++ but it seems not fully compatible - and I need to decrypt data encrypted in PHP using linux libmcrypt.

I found only cygwin version of libmcrypt but no .lib files or header.

I'm using RIJNDAEL_128 - maybe there is easier way to decrypt it in Visual C++?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working libmcrypt version compatible with Visual Studio 
It is here http://files.edin.dk/php/win32/mcrypt/dev/ and worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if Crypto++ didn't do the job frankly. It is a bit awkward to use and is fairly badly documented, but I have found it very powerful in the past.

By RIJNDAEL_128 I am assuming you mean AES? In which case, [Crypto++ can help](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_a_e_s.html) . This [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/BlockCiphers.aspx) ought to be a good starting point too.

Comment: The problem is that the encrypted data was using 8-byte long key, which seems to be not supported by Crypto++ implementation (probably for valid reason, and the encoding code is actually bad but i had to deal with it)