# Compiling libmcrypt as a C++ library

Tags: php, c++, c

I downloaded from sourceforge libmcrypt source of 2.5.8 version from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz/download)

I did few researches and I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815667/libmcrypt-and-ms-visual-c) :

From [this website](http://files.edin.dk/php/win32/mcrypt/dev/), I downloaded the compiled .lib and .dll , and yeah they worked fine. The version available from this website is the 2.5.7. I wanted to compile the 2.5.8 by myself but with a little modify. Actually, I would like to compile an unique library without the need of a DLL.
Can someone tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried cmake?

Comment: Never heard about it, I'm gonna search on google about this. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: "an unique library without the need of a DLL" - do you mean a library for static linking? And what does that have to do with PHP?

Comment: Yeah I meant a library for static linking. Actually as far as I know mcrypt is designed for PHP, but I guess I have added a junk tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. It might be what you are looking for.

http://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/linux/how-to-build-apache-php5-and-mysql-from-source-the-hard-way/

Comment: I saw the link, it explain how install the package mcrypt on linux(I guess after installation it can be included in C++ without problems). Actually I'm using Windows, how could I install it on windows?

Comment: I m pretty sure that cmake is the answer for this. Download cmake , open cmd , go the dir where the source is extracted and type cmake -G "Visual Studio 2010". Try desect the errors and dependencies , if any.  The goal is , it basically builds a VS project taking all the source file in the directory. After which you can simply open the project make your changes and build your own customized .lib or dll file whichever u require.

Comment: It is asking me for a CMakeList.txt, and I don't know what to put in here, never used this software, can you give me some tips?

Comment: Ok well my actual problem is that(I'm using CMake GUI) :

CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target:mcrypt

What can I do for fix that?